# Numpy: slice matrix to remove one row and column

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given an n by n matrix (technically an np.array) L, I wish to remove the kth row and kth column. This line of code works as expected (it selects the 1st through 3rd rows and columns):

```
Lt = L[(1,2,3),(1,2,3)]
```

When I try to replace (1,2,3) by a dynamically generated tuple excluding the k, it fails:

```
keep = (i for i in range(n) if i != k)
Lt = L[keep,keep]
# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> keep = (i for i in range(n) if i != k)
> ```

This is a generator expression, not a generated tuple itself; instead, try

```
keep = tuple(i for i in range(n) if i != k)
```